# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (anonymous function) -document.body.setCapture(); In chrome

Tags: javascript, dhtml

I am getting error mentioned in title on Debugger console while loading my jsp page in chrome.
on mozila and IE it is working fine.
below is the code snippet from javascript which is causing error-
`document.body.setCapture();`

Comment: That usually means that the function hasn't been declared yet.  You need to include a javascript file or define the function setCapture   before you try to use it.

Comment: above function needs to be implemented by browser I think. I have found on web that this function is not supported by chrome. any workaround for this? in case you know

Comment: setCapture is not a standard JS function, it was IE-only until Mozilla implemented it; and AFAIK IE 9+ isn't supposed to support it either (unless it's part of their 'backwards compatible' mode)